# Power BI taking min value from Multiple text columns

Tags: powerbi, dax, reporting

I have these data

```
ID  Daig 1  Daig 2  Daig 3  Daig 4
AA1     5    X        X      2
AA2     X    1        4      X
AA3     7    3        X      X
AA4     X    X        2      6
AA5     X    X        X      3
```

I want to extract the min values from the columns ignoring the text(X)
I wrote the below DAX

```
Min Value = VAR V1 = IF(Data[Daig 1 ]="X",100,VALUE(Data[Daig 1 ]))
            VAR V2 = IF(Data[Daig 2]="X",100,VALUE(Data[Daig 1 ]))
            VAR V3 = IF(Data[Daig 3]="X",100,VALUE(Data[Daig 1 ]))
            VAR V4 = IF(Data[Daig 4]="X",100,VALUE(Data[Daig 1 ]))
            VAR temp = {V1, V2, V3, V4}
            RETURN
            MINX(Data,temp)
```

and it give error
[image]

Expected Output

[image]

Comment: As I see you put for every var (third parameter) Data[Daig1] and this is incorrect and probably generates this error message.

Comment: @msta42a How can I correct it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is a measure:

```
Min Value =
MIN (
    MIN (
        MIN (
            VALUE ( SUBSTITUTE ( SELECTEDVALUE ( Data[Daig 1] ), "X", 999 ) ),
            VALUE ( SUBSTITUTE ( SELECTEDVALUE ( Data[Daig 2] ), "X", 999 ) )
        ),
        VALUE ( SUBSTITUTE ( SELECTEDVALUE ( Data[Daig 3] ), "X", 999 ) )
    ),
    VALUE ( SUBSTITUTE ( SELECTEDVALUE ( Data[Daig 4] ), "X", 999 ) )
)
```

And this approach i use as new calculated column:

```
Min_Value = 

var __innerTab = 
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        GENERATE( VALUES(Data[ID])
    , ROW(
        "d1", IF(Data[Daig 1]="X",100,VALUE(Data[Daig 1])),
        "d2", IF(Data[Daig 2]="X",100,VALUE(Data[Daig 2])),
        "d3", IF(Data[Daig 3]="X",100,VALUE(Data[Daig 3])),
        "d4", IF(Data[Daig 4]="X",100,VALUE(Data[Daig 4]))))
        ,
        "min", min(min( Min([d1], [d2]),[d3]),[d4]))
return
__innerTab
```

[image]